# ITRS Geneos : Get number of rows in a dataview using REST Client

Tags: geneos, itrs

I am able to publish json message to Geneos and show as a dataview in Geneos GUI using https://docs.itrsgroup.com/docs/geneos/6.5.0/data-collection/rest-api.html .

Is there a way to make REST GET call on geneos dataview and get all data to rest client?

I tried to use following code however it seems geneos does not support GET method -

```
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   Object forObject = restTemplate.getForObject("http://host:port/v1/managedEntity/entity-name/sampler/test/dataview/ViewName", Object.class);
```